# Changing Gym Environment Mid Training

Tags: deep-rl, gym

I am using a custom gym environment for a research project. As my agent solves the environment, I want the task to get progressively harder. Right now, I am doing that like so:

```
if correct_solved == 20:
    current_knot += 1
    env.starting_braid = knot_list[current_knot % len(knot_list)]
    state = env.reset()
    correct_solved = 0
```

Where `env.starting_braid` is what determines the task for the agent to solve.

I fear, however, that the environment is not actually changing, so the task is staying as is.

Am I doing this the right way? Is this even a possible task?

Thank you.

Comment: As this is a custom environment, it is not possible to answer here. The correct answer depends on what setting `env.starting_braid` end then doing `env.reset()` actually does. To me, it looks logically correct and that the agent should be looping through different starting braids in index order. This also depends on the code incrementing `correct_solved` as you are expecting it to as well - you don't show that, but even if you did we still don't know the environment so cannot say whether what you are doing will work as expected.